# Docker + Cassandra ulimit error

Tags: cassandra, docker

I am trying to start a cassandra (not dsc) server on Docker (ubuntu 14.04). When I run `service cassandra start` (as root), I get

```
/etc/init.d/cassandra: 82: ulimit: error setting limit (Operation not permitted)
```

line 82 of that file is

```
ulimit -l unlimited
```

I'm not really sure what I need to change it to.

Comment: I wonder if there is a safe/reasonable value to set to w.r.t. Cassandra if unlimited is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short intro into **ulimit**: [RESOURCE LIMITS ON UNIX SYSTEMS (ULIMIT)](http://www.unixmantra.com/2013/06/resource-limits-on-unix-systems-ulimit.html).
The command this init script is trying to issue is supposed to set the max locked memory limit to, well, unlimited. Should succeed for root. Does **whoami** print **root**?

**UPD:** further research led me to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/T45Kc9vD804) Google Groups discussion. Hopefully it will clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 9):

I would expect you would get that warning but that Cassandra would continue to start up and run correctly. As pointed out in the other answer, Docker restricts certain operations for safety reasons. In this case, the Casssandra init script is trying to allow unlimited locked memory. Assuming you are running with swap disabled (as it is a Cassandra best practice) then you can safely ignore this error.

I run Cassandra in Docker for my development environment and also get this warning, but Cassandra starts and runs just fine. If it is not starting up, check the cassandra log files for another problem.

Comment: You may also be missing the cassandra subdirectories.  Make sure to create the data, saved_caches and commitlog folders

Comment: I ran into this as well, but now that I upgraded to Mac High Sierra and switched from Docker Toolbox (Docker via VirtualBox) to native Docker for Mac, when I start Cassandra, it doesn't startup unlike before my OS/Docker upgrade. Strange. Cassandra log didn't indicate anything, `/var/log/cassandra` is empty. Any ideas?

Comment: @bruceg, where do we create those subdirectories (if missing)?

Comment: @David they are usually under /var/lib/cassandra but check your cassandra config: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__commitlog_directory

Answer (score 1):

/etc/init.d/cassandra start/restart/status will not work because init system is not running inside the container so the available option is to restart the container

docker restart "container id or container name"